# Is $y=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$ injective?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Consider the function $y=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$ defined on $(-1,1)$. I am supposed to show that it is injective.

I reason in this way. Let $a,b\in(-1,1)$. Assume $\frac{a}{1-a^2}=\frac{b}{1-b^2}$. I want to show that $a=b$.

Therefore $a(1-b^2)-b(1-a^2)=0$.

Therefore $(a-b)+ab(a-b)=0$.

Therefore $ab=-1$. But this implies $a\neq b$.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks very much for helping.

Comment: Therefore $ab = -1$ **or** $a - b = 0$...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Way 1**

But $ab=-1$ is impossible if $a,b\in (-1,1)$. Therefore, if $a,b\in (-1,1)$, 
$$(a-b)(ab+1)=0\implies a=b,$$
and thus it's injective.

**Way 2**

$$\left(\frac{x}{1-x^2}\right)'=\frac{x^2+1}{(1-x^2)^2}>0$$
for all $x\in(-1,1)$ and thus strictly increasing. Moreover, $x\longmapsto \frac{x}{1-x^2}$ is continuous on $(-1,1)$ and thus, it's injective on $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4):

**Way 3**. Since $f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^2} = x+x^3+x^5+x^7+\ldots$ over $(-1,1)$ we have
$$ f'(x) = 1+\underbrace{3x^2}_{\geq 0}+\underbrace{5x^4}_{\geq 0}+\ldots \geq 1 $$
hence $f$ is increasing on $(-1,1)$.

Comment: This is also nice. Thanks for adding.